# Address of entry point

Tags: exe, portable-executable, entry-point

I am using the following code to find out the address of the entry point for a file called linked list.exe, but it outputs a big number of the kind 699907 whereas the size of the file itself is only 29Kb, so what does this number mean and how can I find the address of the entry point?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<strstream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<WinNT.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fp; 
if((fp = fopen("linked list.exe","rb"))==NULL)
    std::cout<<"unable to open";
int i ;
char s[2];
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER imdh;
fread(&imdh,sizeof(imdh),1,fp);
fseek(fp,imdh.e_lfanew,0);

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS imnth;
fread(&imnth,sizeof(imnth),1,fp);

printf("%d",imnth.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `AddressOfEntryPoint` is the relative virtual address of the entry point, not the raw offset in the file. It holds the address of the first instruction that will be executed when the program starts.

Usually this is not the same as the beginning of the code section. If you want to get the beginning of the code section, you should see the `BaseOfCode` field.

Answer (score 2):

The file is getting opened in memory that's why the address of entry point number is very big. The system provides available memory to file hence, base address always changes when file is opened in memory.

If you want to access actual disk offset of AEP i.e. address of entry point please find below snippet of code.

```
    LPCSTR fileName="exe_file_to_parse";
    HANDLE hFile; 
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileBase;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;

    hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("\n CreateFile failed in read mode \n");
        return 1;
    }

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

    if(hFileMapping==0)
    {
        printf("\n CreateFileMapping failed \n");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

    if(lpFileBase==0)
    {
        printf("\n MapViewOfFile failed \n");
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;  //pointer to dos headers

    if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        //if it is executable file print different fileds of structure
        //dosHeader->e_lfanew : RVA for PE Header
        printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched");

        //pointer to PE/NT header
        peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);

        if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        {
            printf("\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n");
            // valid executable 
            //address of entry point
            DWORD ptr = peHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
            printf("\n RVA : %x \n",ptr); // this is in memory address
            //suppose any one wants to know actual disk offset of "address of entry point" (AEP)

            sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader);
            UINT nSectionCount = peHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
            UINT i=0;
            for( i=0; i<=nSectionCount; ++i, ++sectionHeader )
            {
                if((sectionHeader->VirtualAddress) > ptr)
                {
                    sectionHeader--;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(i>nSectionCount)
            {
                sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader);
                UINT nSectionCount = peHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
                for(i=0; i<nSectionCount-1; ++i,++sectionHeader);
            }

            DWORD retAddr = ptr - (sectionHeader->VirtualAddress) +
                    (sectionHeader->PointerToRawData);
            printf("\n Disk Offset : %x \n",retAddr+(PBYTE)lpFileBase);
            // retAddr+(PBYTE)lpFileBase contains the actual disk offset of address of entry point

        }
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        //getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Not Matched \n");
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }
```